# How to get rid of unwanted sessions in the mongodb database,

Tags: node.js

I am creating a nodejs app in which I used express-session and connect-mongodb-session packages to identify users, now it becomes problem when I use csurf package. csruf package uses session to create csrf tokens and verify them. Now even if user clicks on logout, req.session.destroy is called and user is redirected to login page, Now in login page, I am using csurf as I mentioned above, So user's old session is destroyed and new session is created, Now my problem is:

When user clicks on logout button, he is redirected to login page and new session is created for the same user (old one is destroyed) but if user close the browser, his new session is still in the database, and when he again opens my site, new session is created for the same user again which is causing extra load on my database, Database  I am using is mongodb...

Also tell me if there is the way to remove unwanted sessions from the database,

Hope so I explained my problem well to you sir,

Comment: One technique is to keep a timestamp of last access for the session and then periodically remove any sessions that haven't been accessed in some amount of time of your choosing.  You could also limit a given user to no more than X sessions (getting rid of the oldest when a single user has more than X sessions).